# Increase disk space in AWS EC2 t2.small

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am trying to expand disk space of t2.small instance from 8gb to 12gb using following video tutorial.
Video : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/
When I expand disk space did loss data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding an Amazon EBS volume will *not* lose data.

During the Modify process, additional space is allocated to virtual disk and all data is preserved. You will need to tell the operating system that the disk has expanded so that it uses the new space (on Linux, use `resize2fs`).

Please note that you cannot modify a disk to make it *smaller*.